# Wallpaper and Unity UI text smears

Tags: 13.10, xorg, 14.04, screen, gui

I have the same problem as in this previously asked and not answered question:
[What may cause the desktop wallpaper to be scrambled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388708/what-may-cause-the-desktop-wallpaper-to-be-scrambled)

Here are some of the recommended cli commands to post here:

sudo lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

sudo uname -a:

```
Linux igmuska-1525 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video:

`ii xserver-xorg-video-all            1:7.7+1ubuntu8       amd64 X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii xserver-xorg-video-ati            1:7.3.0-1ubuntu3     amd64 X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii xserver-xorg-video-cirrus         1:1.5.2-1build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- Cirrus display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-fbdev          1:0.4.4-1build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl      0.6.0-0ubuntu4       amd64 X.Org X server -- graphics acceleration module based on OpenGL
ii xserver-xorg-video-intel          2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1  amd64 X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-mach64         6.9.4-1build1        amd64 X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-mga            1:1.6.3-1build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- MGA display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-modesetting    0.8.1-1build1        amd64 X.Org X server -- Generic modesetting driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-neomagic       1:1.2.8-1build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-nouveau        1:1.0.10-1ubuntu2    amd64 X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-openchrome     1:0.3.3-1build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- VIA display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-qxl            0.1.1-0ubuntu3       amd64 X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-r128           6.9.2-1build1        amd64 X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-radeon         1:7.3.0-1ubuntu3     amd64 X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-s3             1:0.6.5-0ubuntu4     amd64 X.Org X server -- legacy S3 display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-savage         1:2.3.7-2ubuntu2     amd64 X.Org X server -- Savage display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion  1:1.7.7-2build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- SiliconMotion display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-sis            1:0.10.7-0ubuntu6    amd64 X.Org X server -- SiS display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-sisusb         1:0.9.6-2build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-tdfx           1:1.4.5-1build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- tdfx display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-trident        1:1.3.6-0ubuntu5     amd64 X.Org X server -- Trident display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-vesa           1:2.3.3-1build1      amd64 X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii xserver-xorg-video-vmware         1:13.0.2-2ubuntu1    amd64 X.Org X server -- VMware display driver`

sudo lspci | grep VGA:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
```

I have also installed and ran CompizConfig Settings Manager on a dead, but hopeful, end.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 1525, 3GB memory. Chromium seems to be the elephant in the room. I've had the smearing issue with both 13.10 and now 14.04. I have noticed through run repeatedly "free -m" that my swap is rarely used as shown below:

free -m:

             `total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3000       2260        739        209         42        973
-/+ buffers/cache:       1244       1755
Swap:         3059        242       2817`

I've not found a suitable solution except for a reboot, which is unacceptable for obvious reasons. I did, however, a workaround:
Go to Settings, change to another wallpaper, change back to my desired wallpaper, fixing the smearing; then to clear up the smeared GUI text, I switched from the default theme "Ambiance" to "Radiance".

Comment: Have you tried to change graphics drivers? I recall having similar issues in previous releases and changing drivers normally fixed it.

Comment: I tried, and still using, the Intel Graphics drivers for Linux recommended from the above, I just forgot to add that.